# Simply connected depending on topology example?

Tags: general-topology

An example of set $A$ and underlying space $R$, s.t. $A$ is simply connected in $R$ with topology $X$ but not in $R$ with topology $Y$.

Interval $[0,a]$ is disconnected by including half-open intervals in the topology.

any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest nontrivial example would probably be to take $A=R=[0,1)$. With the standard topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is simply connected because it is homotopy equivalent to a point. On the other hand, we can view $A$ as $S^1$, since $[0,1)$ parametrizes $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ via $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$. With this topology, we have $\pi_1(A)=\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb{Z}$.